# I tried using local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to clear the value of text inside the input on the click of a button:-
Here is my code:
'''

```
<head>

<script>

function myfunction1() { //remember code var

   texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').value;

   localStorage.setItem('mynumber', texttosave);

   document.getElementById('remember').value = ''

}

function myfunction2() { //recall code

   document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML =

   localStorage.getItem('mynumber');


}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="textline" />

<button id="remember" onclick='myfunction1()'>remember text</button>

<button id="recaller" onclick='myfunction2()'>recall text </button>

<p id="recalledtext">Loading</p>

</body>

</html>'''
```

I have did the correct thing, I think but please help as it is not working.

Comment: You're trying to clear the button's value, not the input field. Flagging to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the value into a variable:

```
function myfunction2() { //recall code
   // ...
   var  my_number = localStorage.getItem('mynumber');
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary (and breaks the code.) The original code already uses the value directly.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem is that you dont do anything with the data you read from local storage.

A quick fix below.

```
function myfunction2() { //recall code

   document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML =

   document.getElementById('remember').value = localStorage.getItem('mynumber')


}
```

Comment: The line breaks are a bit unconventional, but the first part of the assignment operation is on the first line of the function.